# Why is my DataGrid going off screen no matter what solution I try?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout, datagrid

I am new to C# and WPF trying to get what I should think is a simple thing, but it doesn't work.

I have a data grid being populated by SQL, and no matter what I try, I can't get the `Height` of the `DataGrid` to stay within the window. It always just extends down. I want it to be dynamic to the window size.

My very simple code is below, or at least this most recent iteration.

```
<Page x:Class="TMSMaintenance.PaymentError"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TMSMaintenance"
      Title="PaymentError">

    <!--<DataGrid Name="MydataGrid" CanUserAddRows="False" SelectionMode="Single" />-->

        <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>              
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >

            <DataGrid x:Name="MydataGrid" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                      MinHeight="100" 
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">                    
            </DataGrid>               
        </DockPanel>           
    </Grid>        
</Page>
```

I have tried wrapping in a `ScrollView` - it didn't work. I tried setting the `Height` by binding it to the window - it didn't work.  I have tried the `Grid.RowDefinition Height = "*"`  and `"1*"` - it didn't work.  `VerticalAlignment = "Stretch"` also didn't work.

So what am I missing?

Edit: Maybe I should also say that this is on a `Page` file called within a frame tag. Not sure if it makes a difference here.

```
 <StackPanel CanVerticallyScroll="True" CanHorizontallyScroll="True">
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0">
            <Button Content="Files Lookup" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
            <Button Content="Payment Error" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
            <Button Content="Carrier Maintenance" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
            <Button Content="Payment File" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
        </StackPanel>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <Frame x:Name="MainFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" ></Frame>
        </ScrollViewer>               
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Anything you put into a (vertical) StackPanel isn't resized vertically. The StackPanel just extends as far as its child elements require. Put your Frame into a Grid or DockPanel. Besides that, setting the StackPanel's CanVerticallyScroll and CanHorizontallyScroll properties has no effect. Read the remarks on their respective documentation pages.

Comment: I edited your question. First, I removed the forced tags from the title - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) why. Then, I changed your sample code to be *minimal* (see [mcve]). Your samples should not contain any code that is not relevant for the things you're asking about.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Clemens I had read that my self while exploring the options, my Data grid is not within a stackpanel though so I don't believe that would be the issue.  I did try a version of this code where I removed the stackpanel and all it's content and it made no difference.

Comment: @Clemens, I see what you mean about the stack panel now, the one on the main window is what you where referring to I think.  so ignore my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of that `DockPanel`. `Grid` is a much more flexible container for controls and you don't need to pack container into container at all. This alone should do the trick.

Good practice is to not use `DockPanels` at all. Never. Everything you can achieve with `DockPanels` can be achieved with `Grids` (with a bit more of coding, but it gives you more flexible solution and better maintainability of your code).

Also get rid of `VerticalContentAlignment` (not needed in case you described) and you don't need to define `VerticalAlignment` (nor `HorizontalAlignment`) to Stretch, since it's a default value of that property.

**EDIT:**
I haven't noticed the second sample of your code. Everything I wrote before still applies and will make your code better, but I think your problem is with nesting your `Page` in your main container (`Window` or whatever it is).

Try replacing:

```
<StackPanel CanVerticallyScroll="True" CanHorizontallyScroll="True">
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0">
            <Button Content="Files Lookup" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
            <Button Content="Payment Error" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
            <Button Content="Carrier Maintenance" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
            <Button Content="Payment File" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
        </StackPanel>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <Frame x:Name="MainFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" ></Frame>
        </ScrollViewer>               
    </StackPanel>
```

To:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"
                Orientation="Horizontal" 
                Margin="0,10,0,0">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,10,0" />
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>

        <Button Content="Files Lookup"/>
        <Button Content="Payment Error"/>
        <Button Content="Carrier Maintenance"/>
        <Button Content="Payment File"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <Frame x:Name="MainFrame" 
            Grid.Row="1"
            NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />
</Grid>
```

I have also simplified your styling on `Buttons` and I'd recommend you to change your `Page` to `UserControl`.

Comment: I'll give this a try when I get a chance today and let you know how it goes.  I had suspected that it may actually be from frame.  thanks for the pointers.

Comment: This worked, thanks for the insight and suggestions, I'm learning WPF so it's good to learn some best practices.

Comment: Glad I could help :)